I keep getting the error "The constructor FogDevice(int, String, int, int, int, int, int) is undefined" even after importing the necessary library
This is my java code in iFogSim:
package org.fog.test.perfeval;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Host;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Log;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Pe;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Storage;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.power.PowerHost;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.RamProvisionerSimple;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.overbooking.BwProvisionerOverbooking;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.overbooking.PeProvisionerOverbooking;
import org.fog.application.AppEdge;
import org.fog.application.AppLoop;
import org.fog.application.Application;
import org.fog.application.selectivity.FractionalSelectivity;
import org.fog.entities.Actuator;
import org.fog.entities.FogBroker;
import org.fog.entities.FogDevice;
import org.fog.entities.FogDeviceCharacteristics;
import org.fog.entities.Sensor;
import org.fog.entities.Tuple;
import org.fog.placement.Controller;
import org.fog.placement.ModuleMapping;
import org.fog.placement.ModulePlacementEdgewards;
import org.fog.placement.ModulePlacementMapping;
import org.fog.policy.AppModuleAllocationPolicy;
import org.fog.scheduler.StreamOperatorScheduler;
import org.fog.utils.FogLinearPowerModel;
import org.fog.utils.FogUtils;
import org.fog.utils.TimeKeeper;
import org.fog.utils.distribution.DeterministicDistribution;


public class dart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize CloudSim
        CloudSim.init(1, null, false);

        // Create the FogDevice for the DART buoy
        FogDevice dartBuoy = createDartBuoy();

        // Simulate sensor readings
        simulateSensorReadings(dartBuoy);

        // Start simulation
        CloudSim.startSimulation();
        CloudSim.stopSimulation();
    }

    private static FogDevice createDartBuoy() {
        // Parameters: id, name, mips, ram, bw, storage, upFogDeviceId
        int dartBuoyId = 1; // Unique ID for the DART buoy
        String dartBuoyName = "DARTBuoy";
        int mips = 1000; // MIPS (Million Instructions Per Second)
        int ram = 512; // RAM in MB
        int bw = 1000; // Bandwidth in Mbps
        int storage = 10000; // Storage in MB
        int upFogDeviceId = -1; // -1 indicates no parent device

        // Create the DART buoy device
        FogDevice dartBuoy = new FogDevice(dartBuoyId, dartBuoyName, mips, ram, bw, storage, upFogDeviceId);
        return dartBuoy;
    }

    private static void simulateSensorReadings(FogDevice dartBuoy) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double pressure = generateRandomPressure();
            double temperature = generateRandomTemperature();

            // Log readings
            System.out.println("Sensor Readings from " + dartBuoy.getName() + ":");
            System.out.println("Pressure: " + pressure + " hPa");
            System.out.println("Temperature: " + temperature + " °C");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulate time delay between readings
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static double generateRandomPressure() {
        // Generate random pressure between 1000 and 1100 hPa
        return 1000 + Math.random() * 100;
    }

    private static double generateRandomTemperature() {
        // Generate random temperature between 0 and 30 °C
        return Math.random() * 30;
    }
}

While trying to create DART buoy component (comment: // Create the DART buoy device), I keep getting the error saying "The constructor FogDevice(int, String, int, int, int, int, int) is undefined" even though the library needed for the constructor is present.
How could this be resolved?
I am expecting the output as sensor reading in the following format:
Sensor Readings:
Pressure: 1034.56 hPa
Temperature: 22.45 °C
Sensor Readings:
Pressure: 1101.23 hPa
Temperature: 18.76 °C

Looking at the source code (https://github.com/Cloudslab/iFogSim/blob/main/src/org/fog/entities/FogDevice.java), it really looks like there's no such ctor. Where did you see a reference to a ctor with this signature?
